# Who exactly is Sam here?

Tags: underwater

In *Underwater (2020)*, Price discovers that only two of the pods are functional. Price and Haversham
manage to get the ailing Smith into a pod, and Price persuades Haversham to
take the last one:

> Norah: Do you know what I would do for one more second? Just one more
> second with **Sam**? Anything. Anything. Go. You have a whole life.

Who exactly is Sam here?